# Issue with mvel2 - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

We are running Elasticsearch Bulk update (elasticsearch uses MVEL)

And we are getting below error

**** COMPILER BUG! REPORT THIS IMMEDIATELY AT http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/mvel2
Expression:

```
 int cIndex= 0; 
if(ctx._source.xId == 46461){
    if(ctx._source.containsKey("attributes") && ctx._source.attributes.size() > 0){
        for(cIndex = 0; cIndex < ctx._source.attributes.size(); cIndex++){
            if(ctx._source.attributes[cIndex].attributeName != null && ctx._source.attributes[cIndex].attributeName.indexOf("select") >= 0 && ((ctx._source.attributes[cIndex].attributeValue == "Oy") || (ctx._source.attributes[cIndex].containsKey("attributeValueId") && ctx._source.attributes[cIndex].attributeValueId != null && ctx._source.attributes[cIndex].attributeValueId == "One") && ctx._source.attributes[cIndex].attributeName == "attribute_select_1403272286210_2498")){
                ctx._source.attributes[cIndex].attributeValue = "Oye";
                ctx._source.attributes[cIndex].attributeValueId = "One";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine for few records and not working for few records.
Did anybody face this issue? Not sure if ES has to update mvel version
Any around is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting some exception, if yes then please show the stacktrace as well.
Or is it something expression compilation issue, or execution issue.

Comment: No, no exception, it just displays

**** COMPILER BUG! REPORT THIS IMMEDIATELY AT http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/mvel2 Expression:

followed by the above text

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed in  "2.2.0", which `version` of `MVEL` you are using.
Can you try with `<mvel.version>2.2.0.Final</mvel.version>`

Also please refer the link here http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVEL-299